# Correct value for innodb_buffer_pool_size on a server with 130gb of ram?

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb

well i have a big server with 130gb of ram and i have running in this machine a big system that make alot of simultaneous connections to mysql with many queries.

I need some help to set correct value to innodb_buffer_pool_size and if i need to set more some configs, my 'my.cnf' has theses configs:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

max_connect_errors=100
open-files=10000

interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30

max_connections=700

max_allowed_packet=5M
tmp_table_size=50M
max_heap_table_size=56M

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size=10M
query_cache_limit = 10M

sort_buffer_size=15M
read_buffer_size=15M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
join_buffer_size=60M
key_buffer_size=10M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=20M

thread_cache_size = 40

key_buffer=20M
key_buffer_size =20M
open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM

innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3500M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500M

back_log=100
expire_logs_days        = 1
max_binlog_size         = 10M

tmpdir = /var/mysqltmpdir

long_query_time=1
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
bind-address   =  *
port = 3306
```

Comment: nobody can give you a correct answer for this. There are many other things. how many table from which ENGINE, how many connections, how big are the results and insert, if the system only for DB or runs other tasks ,most read or write system and so on. the normal innodb_buffer_pool_size is 70-80 % of the free memory

Comment: `default-storage-engine=MyISAM` should not be in there, especially if you're tuning InnoDB.

Comment: My take on the question:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a sample that calculates the used memory. if you have config your server you can see if there free memory or do you have use to mutch:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_buffer_size';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'thread_stack';
SET @kilo_bytes = 1024;
SET @mega_bytes = @kilo_bytes * 1024;
SET @giga_bytes = @mega_bytes * 1024;
SET @innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2 * @giga_bytes;
SET @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16 * @mega_bytes;
SET @innodb_log_buffer_size = 8 * @mega_bytes;
SET @thread_stack = 192 * @kilo_bytes;
SELECT
( @@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@tmp_table_size
+ @innodb_buffer_pool_size + @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
+ @innodb_log_buffer_size
+ @@max_connections * (
@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size
+ @@join_buffer_size + @@binlog_cache_size + @thread_stack
) ) / @giga_bytes AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
```

**sample small server**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size';
+---------------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name                   | Value   |
+---------------------------------+---------+
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 8388608 |
+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_buffer_size';
+------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name          | Value    |
+------------------------+----------+
| innodb_log_buffer_size | 16777216 |
+------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'thread_stack';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| thread_stack  | 294912 |
+---------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @kilo_bytes = 1024;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @mega_bytes = @kilo_bytes * 1024;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @giga_bytes = @mega_bytes * 1024;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2 * @giga_bytes;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16 * @mega_bytes;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @innodb_log_buffer_size = 8 * @mega_bytes;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET @thread_stack = 192 * @kilo_bytes;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**and now the Query**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT
    -> ( @@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@tmp_table_size
    -> + @innodb_buffer_pool_size + @innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
    -> + @innodb_log_buffer_size
    -> + @@max_connections * (
    -> @@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size
    -> + @@join_buffer_size + @@binlog_cache_size + @thread_stack
    -> ) ) / @giga_bytes AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
+---------------+
| MAX_MEMORY_GB |
+---------------+
|        2.3091 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: `tmp_table_size` is per subquery per connection, _not_ a one-time.  `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` is no longer used (depending on version).  Etc.  Bottom line:  There is no formula that correctly computes what we would all like, namely the max memory usage.  Even if there were, it would be pessimistic.